# iPhone 5 and iPad Air calendar Time Zones

Tags: calendar, iphone, ipad, timezone

My calendar on both my iPhone 5 and iPad Air is beyond screwed up. The most common problem is that an entry moves from the time I set for it.

I live in France but I purchased the phone in New York. I thought I found the problem to be related to a time zone preference.

It always defaults to New York no matter how many times I change it to Central European Time.

So I started specifying the Paris time zone on every entry. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

And when I travel to another time zone I have no idea if any of my entries are accurate, mostly not. I really have a very simple calendar life. No linking with other people or work accounts. I don't want to completely reset my devices.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following "Settings".  Make sure under "General > Date & Time", that your iPhone is showing the correct "Time Zone"  You can either have the iPhone determine this automatically (by turning on the "Set Automatically" switch) or you can set it for a specific location.  Do note that in order for this to set itself automatically you need to have location services enables as well.

The next thing I would check is "Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar" and make sure in the "Calendar" section that you've enabled "Time Zone Support".

All of this is covered in this Appple knowledge base article: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4576

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Time and Time zones.

There are 3 time/date settings

One is you device time/date, that should always represent the actual time in the place you are currently residing that is automatically updated by your phone service provider.

The Calender has 2 time zone settings.

One is for the Calender, and the other one is for the Events.

The Events are dependent from the geographical location they are in and your location wrt the event.

Lets take the England vs Italy match today.

Brazil time it starts at 18:00 and for Central European time that would be 23:00.

If you do not travel to Brazil to watch the game:

Set your Event as follows:

[image: not travel]

You will notice the Calender will Automatically cover the Brazilian time to your Time zone (Paris).

[image: paris time]